# Can I create a table as technical user when logged in as user X?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

Inside an Azure DataBricks lakehouse, I want all my tables being created by a single technical user.

I mainly work with notebooks and would like to use a wrapper function to save dataframes to tables. No matter as which user I am calling the wrapper function, the table should always be created by the technical user for security/ownership reasons.

The issue I'm facing is the inside of the wrapper function. How can I "switch" users for creating the table in that case?

After looking at the documentation, I could not find any proper way to do this. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to impersonate another user. Two things you could try:

1. Wrap the process in a job owned by technical user. All objects created by the job would be owned by job owner.
2. [Transfer ownership](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/table-acls/object-privileges.html#assign-owner-to-object) after creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (...);
ALTER TABLE foo OWNER TO other_user;
```